# Android Login Screen/Post Data

Tags: android, authentication

I'm developing a simple application.
I have some views:
-1 for login;
-1 for "mystats";
-1 for post a pictures to a server.

I have some question.
I designed all layout of these Views, and now I need to implement the code.
At the moment, my problem is to pass the username and pass (from the edittext) to server.
Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of server do you have? What kind of protocol does it use?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Android's HttpClient to talk to some server. This server has to provide some sort of web service and can be implemented in Java, Ruby, PHP or whatever. Your android app may then send the given user credentials to the server, the server looks up the user in his database and answers to tell your android app if the login is valid or not.

So to get started, you need to know something about:

1. Web applications / Web services (e.g. RESTful / SOAP)
2. Databse engine / DBMS / SQL (e.g. MySQL)
3. Android's HttpCLient
4. Read about why you have to use https instead of http for this

Google this and read getting started and wikipedia articles you can find.

Sorry, I have answer this in such an abstract way, because your problem is so abstract. When you got started and have concrete questions, you can start asking them.